# Significado y etimología de "al callo"

Tags: etimología, significado, locuciones, dialectos, chile

> Al callo: Sin rodeos (Chile)

> Al callo: (locución adverbial, coloquial) (Chile) Directamente, sin rodeos.

https://dle.rae.es/callo

> Al callo: 1. loc. adv. coloq. Chile. Directamente, sin rodeos.

https://www.scielo.cl/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0071-17132012000100009

- Al callo: Al detalle, con toda precisión, a la medida.

> Al callo: (Chile) Al punto.

Contexto:

Ej1:

> Están **al callo**, al milímetro, en ser los dos los peores de la competición.

EDIT:

- Al callo: Justo, justo a tiempo, que se acomoda.

Ej2:

> Un crack Jarita, esos pases largos de 60 metros **al callo** de Isla o de Beausejour.

Ej3:

> Tu consejo me vino **al callo**.

Ej4:

> Los pantalones me quedaron **al callo**.

Ej5:

> Su pregunta fue **al callo**.

P.D: Me interesa también su origen. Gracias.

Comment: Sigue la formación de otras expresiones que significan lo mismo: *al grano, al chile...*

Comment: El ejemplo que pones (_están al callo_) no corresponde al uso que damos a la expresión en Chile. Un ejemplo más valido sería "tu consejo me vino al callo", es decir, ese consejo era precisamente lo que necesitaba. También "los pantalones me quedaron al callo", "su pregunta fue al callo".

Comment: @Rodrigo Por lo mismo me interesaba en ese contexto. Otro ejemplo: "Un crack Jarita, esos pases largos de 60 metros al callo de Isla o de Beausejour (al callo = justo, justo a tiempo, que se acomoda) Pensaba que tenía también el matiz de parejitos, como igual de malos, en el mismo nivel, peleando por quién no desciende por ej. en una clasificación.

Answer (score 1):

---

Que tal? Expresión "al callo", callo (del lat. «callum»)

En Español tenemos principalmente cinco tipos de significados con este sonido;

- Calló pretérito del verbo callar.
- Cayó pretérito del verbo caer.
- Cayo como una isla pequeña.
- Callos como comida típica (parte de las tripas del cerdo).
- Callo como dureza, normalmente referida a los pies, pero puede ser referida. de forma general a otras partes del cuerpo, así una callosidad también es piel engrosada en las manos.

En este caso "al callo", se localiza a partir del último significado. Hay que entender que las "callocidades", "el callo" en este caso en los pies aparecen al final, en los *extremos* de los pies, igualmente, cuando se habla de callo es posible referirse a los *Extremos* redondeados de las dos ramas de la herradura que se corresponde con los talones en el casco, es decir, en la parte más "extrema", para entenderlo, "*justo cuando termina la extremidad*". Este carácter de "extremo", "justo al fina", es el le va a conferir el sentido de "justo", "al momento", "al punto", "directamente", y de aquí, a "sin rodeos".

En Español también tenemos la expresión "*al pelo*" que viene a expresar lo mismo que "al callo", utilizada para indicar que una cosa es muy adecuada u oportuna para la ocasión, o que se realiza en el momento justo.

Por último, bajo la forma "callo", en Español también existe la expresión "dar el callo", con el significado de *trabajar mucho*.

Espero haber ayudado. Saludos!

Diego M.